# If (A − B) ∪ (B − A) = A ∪ B then A ∩ B = ∅

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just want to make sure I'm thinking of this correctly.

From what I understand, this is basically saying that:

If the union of everything in set A that's not in set B and everything that's in set B but not A = The union of A and B, then set A and B have no common elements.

Which would be true, because the (A - B) ∪ (B - A) part would exclude shared elements.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that 
$$
 (A - B) \cup (B - A) = A\cup B
$$
and you want to prove that 
$$
A\cap B = \emptyset.
$$
Say that there is an element $x\in A\cap B$. You want to prove that no such exist, so assume that is does. Then Now then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. So, certainly, $a\in A\cup B = (A - B) \cup (B - A).$ If an element is in the union of two sets, then it is one of the sets (maybe in both). So $x\in A- B$ or $x\in B- A$. But both of these options don't hold. Saying that, for example, $x\in A - B$ is saying that $x\notin B$ which contradicts that $x\in A\cap B$. Hence no such $x$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true.  Look up symmetric difference.  It is defined as $$(A - B) \cup (B - A),$$ although an equivalent definition is $$(A \cup B) - (A \cap B).$$

Comment: Thanks! symmetric difference is exactly what I was looking for.